# S-suffix string literal in c++ gives error

Tags: c++

Why does this utterly simple code give error:

```
#include <string>  
using namespace std::string_literals;
int main() {
    auto s = "cat"s;
}
```

Give this error:

```
hello.cpp:4:16: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
        auto s = "cat"s;
```

Is this compiler specific because I am reading from official resource like : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx.

My machine runs osx I use terminal and g++ to compile:

```
g++ -v
```

spits out:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I compiled it with

```
g++ -o hello hello.cpp
```

and

```
 g++ -std=c++11 hello.cpp -o hello
```

and they both show errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: `4.2.1` -- Your compiler is old, that's the plain, simple explanation.

Comment: `g++` on OS X is just a symbolic link for `clang++` btw

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `-std=c++14`.

```
g++ -std=c++14 hello.cpp -o hello
```

gcc 7.0.0 with C++11: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1bqQhMueFpI8xVJq

gcc 7.0.0 with C++14: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Tf23uFqatmXkSss2

Comment: With gcc 4.9 you have to do c++14, but norm says it's OK with c++11.

Comment: Not with gcc 6.2.1 it isn't. `-std=c++11` gives "error: ‘string_literals’ is not a namespace-name". Need "-std=c++14" to compile tihs.